# Creating new calendar under google account using Google Calendar API

Tags: android, google-api, calendar, synchronization, gmail

I get the following error when trying to add new calendar under a google
account:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code": 400,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "Invalid resource id value.",
       "reason": "invalid"
     }
   ],
   "message": "Invalid resource id value."
 }
```

Comment: Could you indicate any research you have done or anything you have tried before asking this question?